# JEditorPane syntax highlighting using jsyntaxpane

Tags: java, jeditorpane, jsyntaxpane

I have a JEditorPane in my application and I was loading java files into it using jsyntaxpane and the following code and it was working perfectly:

to highlight

```
jsyntaxpane.DefaultSyntaxKit.initKit();
textarea.setContentType("text/java");
```

to load file in

```
int a = filesToCompileList.getSelectedIndex();
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
textarea.read.read(br, index);
br.close();
textarea.requestFocus();
```

but know i had to change the way i was loading the file in and i am currently loading the files in like

```
File file = new File(filePath);
textarea.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
```

this is loading the files in the way i want but isn't highlighting the text for java files anymore! does anybody know how i can fix this or get java highlighting a different way?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it can not be done if you don't implement your own version of the [jeditorpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html). From the javadoc

> The setPage method can be used to initialize the component from a URL.
>   In this case, the content type will be determined from the URL, and
>   the registered EditorKit for that content type will be set.

So, the mime type of the content will be inherit from the mime type of the url. Call *setContentyType* later will have no effect, as this will change the model of the jeditorpane, cleaning the content. Again from the Javadoc

> NOTE: This has the side effect of changing the model, because the
>   EditorKit is the source of how a particular type of content is
>   modeled. This method will cause setDocument to be called on behalf of
>   the caller to ensure integrity of the internal state.

So you must keep using the read method.